# Add new table in Database from install.xml

Tags: moodle

I am new to `moodle`, I want to create some new table when in moodle, and that too when the initial install is being processed. I made the changes in `moodle\lib\db\install.xml`, but it is not taking update for the new table.

My update in `install.xml` is:

```
<TABLE NAME="user_site" COMMENT="Sites">
    <FIELDS>
        <FIELD LENGTH="3" SEQUENCE="true" TYPE="int" NOTNULL="true" NAME="id"/>
        <FIELD LENGTH="4" SEQUENCE="false" TYPE="int" NOTNULL="true" NAME="site_id"/>
    </FIELDS>
</TABLE>
```

As the `moodle` was not taking the update on its own, so I deleted the config file, in order to re-initiate the install. But it did not accept the changes either.

Any help.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a local plugin with an install.xml rather than modifying the core code.

http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Local_plugins

First create a folder with web server write access

```
local/user_site/db/
```

Then use the xmldb editor to edit the install.xml file

http://docs.moodle.org/dev/XMLDB_editor#Quick_Start

Then create a version file to install the plugin and create the table

```
local/user_site/version.php
```

Comment: I need these tables to be their right from the new installation. Say if I unzip a copy of my moodle somewhere else, then I want these tables to be created during the installation.

Comment: They will be if you include the local plug in in the zip